# Colon of Two ideals in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, noetherian

Is there any example of a commutative ring $R$ with unity and its proper ideal $I$ where **$(I^{k+1} : I) = I^k $** does not hold for some value of k ?

Comment: With $k=0$ you have that the colon ideal is all of $R$ for any proper ideal $I$, right?

Comment: Since the edit you made to your original question invalidated an existing answer, I am reverting that part of the edit. It is simply not fair to move the goalposts after a user has answered your question in good faith.  You should have been more careful proofreading it.  You may create a new post to ask your revised question, but first [read this advice about posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) so that you can ward off closure again.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a simpler answer, but here's one I came up with (assuming you wanted an example where $k\neq 0$).

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be some field, and let $R= \mathbb{F}[x,y]$. Now let $I=(x^4, x^3y, xy^3, y^4)$, that is, all degree 4 monomials **except** for $x^2y^2$.

Then $I^2 = (x^8, x^7y, x^6y^2, x^5y^3, x^4y^4,x^3y^5,x^2y^6, xy^7,y^8)$, that is, all degree $8$ monomials.

Then notice that $x^2y^2$ is in $(I^2:I)$, because multiplying any element of $I$ by a degree 4 monomial will surely get you a degree 8 monomial. But $x^2y^2$ was not in $I$ to begin with.

So $(I^2:I) \supsetneq I$.